# Magento Event dispatch in multishipping checkout

Tags: magento

In my custom module, I want to take some action when various stages of the checkout process are completed. I am using the Magento event dispatch system to achieve this. Unfortunately the event dispatch system in the core product seems a bit haphazard.
One checkout stage is when the user enters their billing address. When using the one page checkout method, I can have an observer for the event:

```
controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling
```

I am not sure if that is the best event to signify a billing address has been entered, but it seems to work ok.

When using the multishipping checkout process, I can’t see a relevant event I can listen for. Billing address and Payment method are on the same checkout stage. The most relevant event I can come up with is:

```
controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_multishipping_overview
```

which is also fired on Place Order.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Log and grep, my friend, log and grep :)  I logged all events while going through a Multi-Shipping checkout flow and here's a dump of the goods.

Not de-duping the list on purpose in case it's of interest which events are fired multiple times and in what order:

controller_action_predispatch_checkout_multishipping_index
controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_multishipping_index
controller_action_predispatch_checkout_multishipping_addresses
controller_action_layout_render_before_checkout_multishipping_addresses
controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_multishipping_addresses
controller_action_predispatch_checkout_multishipping_addressesPost
checkout_type_multishipping_set_shipping_items
controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_multishipping_addressesPost
controller_action_predispatch_checkout_multishipping_shipping
controller_action_layout_render_before_checkout_multishipping_shipping
controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_multishipping_shipping
controller_action_predispatch_checkout_multishipping_shippingPost
checkout_controller_multishipping_shipping_post
controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_multishipping_shippingPost
controller_action_predispatch_checkout_multishipping_billing
controller_action_layout_render_before_checkout_multishipping_billing
controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_multishipping_billing
controller_action_predispatch_checkout_multishipping_overview
controller_action_layout_render_before_checkout_multishipping_overview
controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_multishipping_overview
controller_action_predispatch_checkout_multishipping_overviewPost
checkout_type_multishipping_create_orders_single
controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_multishipping_overviewPost
controller_action_predispatch_checkout_multishipping_success
checkout_multishipping_controller_success_action
controller_action_layout_render_before_checkout_multishipping_success
controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_multishipping_success

Comment: That's what I'm doing, but I go one step further and also look at what stage the events are fired. For instance, `controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_multishipping_billing` looks interesting, but is actually fired when the "Continue to billing information" button is clicked from the "Shipping Information" stage of the checkout process, i.e. **before** the billing address stage. At the stage the billing address is entered (the "Billing Information" stage), the best candidate appears to be the one I mentioned in my post.

Comment: Gotcha, my bad, sorry for assuming you weren't already doing that.  I think that based on the sheer volume of events that got fired in that process I assumed there would have to be one in there to meet your needs.  Are you saying that for example controller_action_predispatch_checkout_multishipping_addressesPost  is less relevant than controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_multishipping_overview for your purposes?

Comment: Hello. The controller_action_predispatch_checkout_multishipping_addressesPost  event is fired when moving from the "Shipping Information" stage to the "Billing Information" stage, but I was looking to find when a user had completed their Billing Address in the checkout process, which would be when moving from the "Billing Information" stage to the "Place Order" stage.

Comment: Ah, right...are you saying no multishipping events whatsoever fire when moving from Billing Information to Place Order?